# d3 selectAll selectAll append append

Tags: d3.js

I would like to build `<ul><li>` stucture where each`<li>` would contain data item in it.

```
d3.select("#myDiv").selectAll("ul").selectAll("li").data(flatData).enter().append("ul").append("li").text(function(d) { return d.label; });
```

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's just one `#myDiv` and one `ul` inside it then:

```
d3.select("#myDiv")
  .select("ul") // or .append("ul")
  .selectAll("li").data(flatData)
  .enter()
    .append("li")
    .text(function(d) { return d.label; });
```

Comment: what confusing me is where to put enter(). I thought that before enter () i'm supposed to select stuff but then/after appending stuff.

Comment: @ses Yeah, it's somewhat confusing. Note that it's important to use `select()` for the `ul` and `selectAll()` for the `li`. The former sets up the parent context, the latter prepares it to be bound to the data. The typical d3 sequence of selectAll-then-bind-then-append works on one level only. If you need to create `ul` elements that are also bound to data (with nested `li`s inside), then you need to have 2-level data (in a 2D array) and bind each to the proper level and use `enter()` twice. Check out examples of the proper way to create html `table`s with d3 to get a better unserstanding.